# R Split a title phrase into sub-phrases of a given maximum length

Tags: r, strsplit

I have an R data frame where the columns have names such as the following:

`"Goods excluding food purchased from stores and energy\nLast = 1.8"`

`"Books and reading material (excluding textbooks)\nLast = 136.1"`

`"Spectator entertainment (excluding video and audio subscription services)\nLast = -13.5"`

There are a large number of columns. I want to insert newline characters where necessary, between words, so that these names consist of parts that are no longer than some given maximum, say MaxLen=18. And I want the last part, starting with the word "Last", to be on a separate line. In the three examples, the desired output is:

`"Goods excluding\nfood purchased\nfrom stores and\nenergy\nLast = 1.8"`

`"Books and reading\nmaterial\n(excluding\ntextbooks)\nLast = 136.1"`

`"Spectator\nentertainment\n(excluding video\nand audio\nsubscription\nservices)\nLast = -13.5"`

I have been trying to accomplish this with strsplit(), but without success. The parentheses and '=' sign may be part of my problem. The "\nLast = " portion is the same for all names.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: It's really _not_ a good idea to have column names like this. Column names should be easy to work with; it's going to be difficult to reference these columns in your code. Presumably you want them like this because you want a final output table or plot to have these as column headers or axis / legend labels, but there will almost certainly be a better way to do this than by giving your columns unmanageable names. This feels very much like an x/y problem, though @MrFlick has given a good solution for the question-as-asked.

Comment: I get your point. But I think these long names work well for my kind of application. See: https://rpubs.com/PhilSmith26/1003211 if you are interested.

Comment: @PhilSmith nice plots. My point is that you don't need to use _column names_ to get plots like that.  Best to keep your column names simple and pass the strip text as a different variable. I suspect that will make your code easier to read and debug. Just passing on some advice I learned the hard way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strwrap` function can help here, though you need to do a bit of work to keep the existing breaks. Consider this option

```
input <- c("Goods excluding food purchased from stores and energy\nLast = 1.8",
"Books and reading material (excluding textbooks)\nLast = 136.1",
"Spectator entertainment (excluding video and audio subscription services)\nLast = -13.5")

strsplit(input, "\n") |>
  lapply(function(s) unlist(sapply(s, strwrap, 18))) |>
  sapply(paste, collapse="\n")
# [1] "Goods excluding\nfood purchased\nfrom stores and\nenergy\nLast = 1.8"                        
# [2] "Books and reading\nmaterial\n(excluding\ntextbooks)\nLast = 136.1"                           
# [3] "Spectator\nentertainment\n(excluding video\nand audio\nsubscription\nservices)\nLast = -13.5"
```

Here we split the existing breaks, add new ones, then put it all back together.